# What mongoexport's error code 7 does mean?

Tags: mongoexport

Where can I find Unix error codes for `mongoexport` CLI?

I'm getting code `7` (instead of expected `0`) and an empty string instead of a JSON response. Nothing really about that in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/).

Answer (score 0):

Let say we have `mongoexport` like:

`mongoexport --db some_db --collection some_collection --query 'query' --fields some_id,some_other_field --jsonArray`

where `query` is `{some_id: {$in: #{Poison.encode!(some_ids)}}...`

The problem is if more than ~`13_000` ids are supplied to the `$in` operator inside the `query` parameter, `mongoexport` will blow up with error code `7` while exporting JSON... I wish they document this somewhere.